# Batch file stops after SQL statement is completed and doesn't continue to exit

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sqlcl

I'm running a simple batch file to execute a SQL statement.

The batch file:

```
cd /D C:\sqlcl\bin

sql username/password@host:port:SID @C:\scripts\statement.sql

exit
```

The SQL statement runs perfectly. It spools the results of the query to a CSV file and returns to the `SQL>` prompt.

The issue is the batch file doesn't go to the next line to exit SQL and the CMD window.  No matter what command I test, the batch file does not go to the 3rd line.

Is there something I need to add to `*.sql` file to force it to end? Am I missing something with using exit?  I've tried `QUIT`, `HOST` to return to CMD, `ECHO` to print something but not matter the command, it never goes to that line but does return to the SQL prompt.

Comment: `echo exit|sql username/password@host:port:SID @C:\scripts\statement.sql` ?

Comment: edit your statement.sql and have the last line be:  exit;

Comment: The last line of the sql statement is "exit;" and it still stops before the exit command in the batch file and returns to the SQL> prompt.  The sql script is below:

set sqlformat csv;
set heading on;
set feedback off;
spool "C:\output\file.csv";
select *...;
spool off;
exit;

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your .sql file to add an exit at the end such as this.

```
set feedback off
set head off
set sqlformat csv
spool emp.csv
select * from emp;
exit
```

Run as you normally are

`$ sql klrice/klrice @spool`

resulting file is a csv as expected.

```
$ more emp.csv
7369,"SMITH","CLERK",7902,17-DEC-80,800,,20,5555555555554444
7499,"ALLEN","SALESMAN",7698,20-FEB-81,1600,300,30,4929043445510803
7521,"WARD","SALESMAN",7698,22-FEB-81,1250,500,30,6011823599867990
7566,"JONES","MANAGER",7839,02-APR-81,2975,,20,375055626849864
7654,"MARTIN","SALESMAN",7698,28-SEP-81,1250,1400,30,4929727676353442
7698,"BLAKE","MANAGER",7839,01-MAY-81,2850,,30,5262511577814781
7782,"CLARK","MANAGER",7839,09-JUN-81,2450,,10,6011983140249807
7788,"SCOTT","ANALYST",7566,09-DEC-82,3000,,20,343764091280047
7839,"KING","PRESIDENT",,17-NOV-81,5000,,10,5186144047197497
7844,"TURNER","SALESMAN",7698,08-SEP-81,1500,0,30,6011331487563093
7876,"ADAMS","CLERK",7788,12-JAN-83,1100,,20,378775397941460
7900,"JAMES","CLERK",7698,03-DEC-81,950,,30,4916225758678451
7902,"FORD","ANALYST",7566,03-DEC-81,3000,,20,378355660338882
7934,"MILLER","CLERK",7782,23-JAN-82,1300,,10,34567
$
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting issue was causing this problem.

In the original SQL file I had exported from SQL Developer, I had not included "exit" at the end. I opened it in Notepad and added "exit".  Every time, I looked at the SQL file, I opened it in Notepad and "exit" was there.

I just opened the SQL file in Notepad+ and "exit" was NOT there. I added it and the batch file now works fine.

I have no idea why this issue happens.